# Add Product Amazon MWS api PHP

Tags: php, api, amazon-mws

How to add products (like product title,images,desc,images,shipping,keywords().. via submit feed.

Even i tested submit feed in scratchpad.
when i SubmitFeed to amazon it return sucessfull response but i did not see any product in my seller account and amazon website Service Response FeedSubmissionInfo FeedSubmissionId 8316233554 FeedType POST_PRODUCT_DATA SubmittedDate 2013-10-31T09:47:02Z FeedProcessingStatus SUBMITTED.

Can anyone please send me example php code.

Someone guide me.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do two things:

1. Check the status and results of your submission as outlined here: [Amazon MWS problem with _POST_INVENTORY_AVAILABILITY_DATA_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5499886/amazon-mws-problem-with-post-inventory-availability-data)
2. Submit [additional feeds for prices, inventory and images](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17434970/2097290).